# Is it possible to adjust Redactor config on a per-user basis?

Tags: redactor

So in the [Redactor config file](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields), I have the standard "[source](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/source/)" plugin enabled:

```
"plugins": ["source"]
```

This is great for the admins who want to go in a play with around with the markup. However, I'd like to avoid certain user types from having that level of control. Essentially I want to stop clients messing with stuff they shouldn't.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with the native Rich Text field in Craft (or any field in Craft since the settings aren't defined on a per-user basis).

You could probably pull this off with a [custom plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that added a field type that extended Craft's Rich Text field and overwrote (at least) the `getIntputHtml()` and `getSettingsHtml()` methods to add per-user settings support.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this Brad. When I've built a plugin for this, I'll update my question.